# Microsoft's Feedback Hub now crashes my UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

The Feedback Hub worked perfectly since I launched my app months ago. Suddenly I tested launching it from within my app so that I could go directly to the feedback hub page for my app and the app just crashed. So then I launched my app in debug mode and tried it again. The app simply crashes with no debug information.

Is this somehow related to me updating to the October update of Windows 10? Or maybe me extending my app's compatibility to Windows 10 1809 (17763)? I like NEVER touched the code that launches the feedback hub and so it is not my doing. This is the code:

```
if (Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement.StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher.IsSupported())
{
   var feedbackLauncher = Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement.StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher.GetDefault();
   await feedbackLauncher.LaunchAsync();
}
```

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue in windows 10 1809. What's your project's targer version? What's the Microsoft Store Services SDK version?

Comment: 17763.1.180914-1434.rs5 ....That might be overkill, lol. But the min  version for the app is 1803 (17134) and the target version is 1809 (17763)

Comment: Okay, so I created a new app and got the same result when I set the min and max supported version to 1803 and 1809, respectively. However, when I changed the target (max) supported version to just 1803 instead of the new 1809, all went well. So there is a compatibility issue here that Microsoft has not fixed.

Comment: Now Microsoft just recently released a fixed October update that I have not yet installed so MAYBE the issue described here has been addressed in that version? O_o

Comment: You could try to install that update.

Comment: I'm trying to get an update on this issue.  I've seen it to.

Comment: Same issue here, anyone managed to get a workaround?

Comment: Getting this as well. Even wrapping it in a try/catch does still crash your app. Not good for any of my apps, they even fail certification because of this crash :-(

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT Did you get an update about this?

Comment: @PatrikSvensson yup found the right people to open the issue against and talking with them.

Comment: 22-01-2019 still not fixed. My app did not pass certification because of this. Changed the target version to 1803 and the feedback hub will open without crashing my app. Microsoft should make this a priority, because not everyone tests their full app when he/she updates the app in the store. Especially not if a function is not changed like opening the feedback hub!

Comment: Great news, Microsoft fixed this in 10.0.5, released on Feb 14, 2019: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdMediator.MicrosoftStoreServicesSDK

Answer (score 2):

FEB 2019 UPDATE

This has now been fixed in version 10.0.5.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdMediator.MicrosoftStoreServicesSDK

Comment: I am facing the same issue with "Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML". Can you plz check if it's the same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407600/app-keeps-crashing-during-certification-when-using-microsoft-advertising-sdk-for

Comment: Unlikely to be the same. Please start a new question and include your repro and crash details.

Comment: Great news, Microsoft fixed this in 10.0.5, released on Feb 14, 2019: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdMediator.MicrosoftStoreServicesSDK

Answer (score 1):

The temporary workaround is to package your app using VS 2019 preview edition, the issue does not repro here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this was fixed in Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement 10.1901.28001