# App keeps crashing during certification when using Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

In my already published app, I tried adding ADs using “Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML” (tried adding reference via both NuGet and msi). On my dev machine both debug and release builds work fine, even .appxbundle created as part of packaging works as expected, but the app always crashes at launch for the reviewer when submitted for review/certification (.appxupload file).

Note: The app is a Desktop Bridge app. There is a UWP app which communicates with a win32 exe. The call to launch Feedback hub or Ads are in the UWP app.

Following are the max and min supported versions of my project-

```
<TargetPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == '' ">10.0.17134.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

I also tried adding following entries in the rd.xml file hoping to fix any reflection related issue, but no luck

```
<Type Name="Microsoft.Advertising" Dynamic="Required All"/>   
<Type Name="Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI" Dynamic="Required All"/>

<Namespace Name="Microsoft.Advertising" Serialize="All"/>   
<Namespace Name="Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI" Serialize="All"/>
```

### Edit

On removing reference to Ad SDK the app passed certification and didn't crash for the reviewer. The app packages which crashed during review had reference to `Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml` `10.1811.1.0`.

Comment: Is there any feedback from the reviewer what is the exact exception of the crash?

Comment: If the suspected Ad SDK was removed, will the review go smoothly?

Comment: I did mail at reportapp@microsoft.com asking for more details of the crash but didn't get a response. Yes on removing the Ad SDK, app passed the certification.

Comment: Is there any way I can deploy the app using .appxupload file, which is submitted for review? So, that I have a faster feedback loop for any fixes I try.

Answer (score 2):

The temporary workaround is to package the app using VS 2019 preview edition.
My app passed certification and did not crash.