# Desktop Bridge Window Store Application fails. Local Installation works

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I have a Desktop Bridge application which launches a UWP window from the menu (Select **Help** > **Contents** to launch the UWP Window). The local installation (**AppPackages\appName_Test\appName_x86_bundle.msixbundle**) works fine.

I've uploaded **AppPackages\appName_x86_bundle.msixupload** to the Microsoft Store but the store version fails to launch the window.  The window opens for a couple of seconds and then shuts down.

Debugging the installed store version I get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x750EB022 (KernelBase.dll) in <MyUwpExeHere>.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80131500 : 'Method 'TreeView.add_ItemInvoked(TypedEventHandler<TreeView, TreeViewItemInvokedEventArgs>)' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in MainPage.Connect(int, object). There may have been a missing assembly.'.
```

The treeview control is from [Microsoft.UI.Xaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml).

Also when the app is locally installed there is a **\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd** file with reference information (including **Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView**) in the install folder.  It is missing from the Store installation.

The AppManifest.xml includes the dependencies:

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.17763.0"/>
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" MinVersion="14.0.26706.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"/>
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml" MinVersion="10.1805.2.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"/>
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.0" MinVersion="2.1810.18003.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"/>
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.7" MinVersion="1.7.25531.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"/>
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7" MinVersion="1.7.25531.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"/>
  </Dependencies>
```

The applications (one 32-bit and one 64-bit) always pass the store certification but the store installations fail as described - on all machines.

The dependency ".appx" files are **not** included in ".msixupload" which I think is expected.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This may not be the only thing missing, but for this type of mixed UWP/classic project you will need to list both VCLibs version as dependencies. You are missing this one: <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.xxxxx.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I got a slightly more specific error message this time ```"Method 'TreeView.add_ItemInvoked(TypedEventHandler<TreeView, TreeViewItemInvokedEventArgs>)' from assembly 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in MainPage.Connect(int, object). There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release."``` but still no luck.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Also changed the TargetPlatformMinVersion in the.csproj from 10.0.15063.0 to 10.0.17763.0 (required by the treeview) which changed the native package dependencies e.g. Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2 to version 2.2.27011.0. So not sure what else could be missing.

Comment: Really don't know what else to try.  Replacing the treeview with the navigation view produces a similar result `Exception thrown at 0x750EB022 (KernelBase.dll) in <UWPExeName>.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80131513 : 'Method 'XamlControlsResources..ctor()' from assembly 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_XamlControlsResources(). There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.'. `

Comment: Does the TreeView control work in a Store deployed plain UWP app? Wondering if this is actually unrelated to the desktop bridge and it just the packagedepency for the UI control is missing from the Store.

Comment: There's a Xaml Controls Gallery app using Microsoft.UI.Xaml so I'm thinking no - I'll try it anyway - see what happens.  I'll also try a custom nav bar and leave Microsoft.UI.Xaml out and see if that works.  Thanks.

Comment: I submitted a trivial UWP with Microsoft.UI.XAML to the Store and it works. As a next step I'll make it a desktop bridge app and see if I can reproduce your error.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to it @StefanWickMSFT -  waiting on my Microsoft.UI.Xaml free update.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce this with my own test app. There is an even easier repro for this problem: Just create a new UWP app with any control from MSFT.UI.XAML and wrap it in a Packaging project. I haven't found an obvious workaround for this yet. Reaching out to the team that owns this to find a resolution.

Comment: That's great news - thanks. Hopeful that the Ad SDK does not have the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407600/app-keeps-crashing-during-certification-when-using-microsoft-advertising-sdk-for) - waiting on store certification.

Comment: It's what I feared unfortunately: ```Exception thrown at 0x750EB022 (KernelBase.dll) in <MyUwpExe>.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80131513 : 'Method 'AdControl..ctor()' from assembly 'Microsoft.Advertising' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_2_AdControl(). There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.'.```.

Comment: Hit continue and ```WinRT originate error - 0x802B000A : 'Cannot create instance of type 'Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.AdControl' [Line: 0 Position: 0]'.```.

Comment: The ad control blows up with [Xaml Islands too](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/65) so I'll be grateful for a workaround.

Comment: I can confirm that both applications installed from the store work after removing Microsoft.UI.Xaml and Microsoft.Advertising.SDK.

Comment: I have confirmed the same. The Store team is investigating.

Comment: @Marx, how did you get the exception stack given the issue does not repro locally and only happens while certification/review?

Comment: @ac-lap - I think you've misread the text.  It always passes certification.  The local installation from **AppPackages\appName_Test** works fine.  The store installed version fails and I get the exception from VS debugging of the downloaded store version.

Comment: @Marx one thing we found so far is that it works correctly when using VS2019 preview to create the app package for Store submission. Not sure if this is something you are able to try, but that would be one workaround for now, until there is a full resolution/fix for this.

Comment: Thanks @StefanWickMSFT .  Just submitted both packages - created using VS 2019 preview. I'll follow up with results.

Comment: That worked!  Great to see it work.  Thank you again @StefanWickMSFT.

Comment: @ac-lap heads up.

Comment: Thanks @Marx, my store submission also passed!

Answer (score 3):

The solution/workaround was to package using VS 2019 Professional preview edition.  Thanks to @StefanWickMSFT for directions.

Comment: Hope to have a better solution soon that will work for VS2017 users. I will update the thread once we have more to share.