# UWP using Windows Desktop Extension Crashes at Launch when Submitting to Store

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I am having troubles getting my app accepted by the Microsoft Store. My app has the following properties:

1. Minimum Windows 10 version: 10.0.17763
2. Maximum Windows 10 version: 10.0.17763
3. References Windows Desktop Extensions for UWP version: 10.0.17763
4. Uses capability: runFullTrust (for good measure, I always check if the required API is present whenever I call the FullTrustProcessLauncher)
5. Desktop component uses .Net Framework 4.6.1
6. Supports Multi-Instance

I have already tried debugging my app in my local machine using Debug and Release configurations with no problems. I have also tried sideloading it to other PCs with no problems either. What might be the cause of the crash when I try submitting it to the store?

If you need more info, would gladly give them if necessary.

#### Additional Info (Store Certification Error)

App Policies: 10.4.2 Usability - App Crashes or Freezes

Notes To Developer

Unfortunately, we can’t test the app, because the app crashes at launch.

Tip: A Windows app may run flawlessly during development and testing, but after submitting it for certification testing, the app may crash or perform unexpectedly. Along these same lines, your app may not perform as expected after publication. You can contact Developer Support at http://aka.ms/storesupport if you need assistance with troubleshooting.

Tested Devices: Acer Iconia W700, Acer Switch 3, (Win 10 S) Microsoft Surface Laptop, High Performance Desktop

Comment: Can you provide the error if so or the message you get when submitting to the store? Or explain the steps that you use to submit?

Comment: @Pimenta i added the error above. I created the appx packages using Visual Studio 2017 with x86, x64, and ARM packages. I have already contacted the store team and they said that the runFullTrust will be granted once my app passes this last error.

Comment: What did you do when the app starts? Can you show some relevant code snippets? In addition, you could try to use [Windows App Certification Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit) to validate and test it locally. Then after the test, you can open the report file and review the results of the test.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I don't do anything special when the app starts, it just navigates to the homepage. I also have validated and tested it using WACK, and it passed every test. I also opened the report to check, and all of them are truly passed except one. I use the Process.Start API in my desktop component, and it just warns me about this when app is used in Win10S, but I have no intention of releasing my app to Win10S devices so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: @Rivolvan Maybe it's not related but still fails if it tries to do the same test you are doing. Can you send this explain to the Store Team to double check if you need to exclude Win10S or create an exception for it?

Comment: @Pimenta I have already included in the submission's developer notes that I want my app to be excluded from Win10S and I also asked why is my app tested in Win10S devices. They responded that they saw my notes and that may app also fails when tested on non-Win10S devices. Once my app passes the test on non-Win10S devices, they will then exclude my app from Win10S.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT do you think, my problem is related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423924/desktop-bridge-window-store-application-fails-local-installation-works?rq=1. I also use the WinUI package although I only use the version 2.1

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but you could try to use its solution to test.

Comment: Did you test your app in "S" Mode? You can also try contacting Developer Support like it says in the message.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I have tried packaging my app using Visual Studio 2019 and submitting it to the store. let's see how this goes.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I have already contacted dev support, and they said that Win10S should not be a problem with my app and that my app fails to run on non-Win10S. I think it has something to do with .net native and winui. But with no clear error message, all i can do is just hope for the best as I submit my app again using VS2019 packaging tools

Comment: OK, if you have any progress, please update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to package the App using Visual Studio 2019. It seems that WinUI is having troubles when paired with the Packaging project. I just hoped that this was documented as I spent months trying to solve this problem. Thank you to everyone who helped me.